# How add element in existing list?

Tags: dart

Assume I have a object list like:

```
var student = [
  Student(name: "vicky", age: 12),
  Student(name: "mani", age: 14),
  Student(name: "karthick", age: 19)
];
```

I would like add another element in my existing student list:

```
var student = [
  Student(name: "vicky", age: 12, index: 0),
  Student(name: "mani", age: 14, index: 1),
  Student(name: "karthick", age: 19, index: 2)
];
```

what's a good way to do this with dart?

Comment: Add the `index` to be part of the `Student` class? Or are you thinking on something else?

Comment: not part of class... I wanna a element during initstate or something else?

Comment: Well, in your example, you are calling the `Student` constructor with a named parameter `index`. This parameter needs to part of the `Student` constructor if you want to use it.

Comment: I have list that's comes from internet I wanna interst their index value

Comment: Please update your example so it actual describes what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's some confusion of terms here - when you add an element to a list, the list itself grows longer, like so:

```
List<int> numbers = [0, 1, 2]; // A list with three elements
numbers.add(3); // Now the list has 4 elements: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

What you seem to be asking though, is how to add a property to a class. What you currently have should be something along these lines:

```
class Student {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Student({required this.name, required this.age});
}
```

If you want the student class to include an index property, you can add it like so:

```
class Student {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  final int index;

  Student({required this.name, required this.age, required this.index});
}
```